# Autocomplete is not working: emacs elpy-mode

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete

I am using emacs 24.3.1 and python 2.7 and I got elpy mode sucessfully installed. Unfortunately, however, autocomplete isn't working, although the auto-complete mode is installed and activated in python's buffer.

Concretely, if I do `import numpy as np` and try to type any numpy object after `np.` I get the mini-buffer message:

> Can't get completions: 'CompletionProposal' object has no attribute 'get_doc'

This is the bit of my init file pertaining to python:

```lisp
(package-initialize)

(elpy-enable)
(elpy-use-ipython)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (abbrev-mode 1)
        (auto-fill-mode 1)
        (linum-mode 1)
        (if (eq window-system 'x)
        (font-lock-mode 1))))
```

Does anyone out there have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

I added jedi-mode to my python-mode-hook as in http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/ and it did the trick.

Comment: jedi mode has been a life-changer